# Blocking the date in jQuery datetimepicker

Tags: jquery, date, datetimepicker

I have a code that, blocking the future 4 days in datetimepicker, but the problem is the number of days is adding in to 4. For example the date today is 28/08/2018 then the output must be "01/09/2018" that will be the output, but the output in my my code is "32/08/2018".

Here's the code

```
//datetimepicker
<input type="text" id="text_checkin">

//jquery script --reference only--
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js"></script>
```

and here's my script"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var d = new Date();

var month = d.getMonth()+1;
var day = d.getDate()  + 4;

var output = ((''+day).length<2 ? '0' : '') + day + '/' 
+ ((''+month).length<2 ? '0' : '') + month 
+ '/' + d.getFullYear();


alert(output);


$("#text_checkin").attr("autocomplete","off");
$("#text_checkout").attr("autocomplete","off");

$('#text_checkin').datetimepicker({
    step: 5
});
$('#text_checkin').datetimepicker({
   minDate: output
});
$('#text_checkin').datetimepicker({
    timepicker:false,
    format: 'd/m/Y',
    formatDate:'d/m/Y'
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct way to offset date is

```
 // date 4 days ahead
    var nextDay = new Date();
    nextDay.setDate(nextDay.getDate() + 4);

    alert(nextDay);
```

Comment: thankyou sir @noman!! But the problem is I don't know how the syntax will be "d/m/Y", and the alert must be `alert(nextDay)` but sir!! THANKYOU SOMUCH!!